# (Blender 2.82) Mantaflow Fluid Simulation not working

Tags: fluid-simulation

So basically I've been trying to get a simple fountain fluid simulation to work. However, there are a lot of times despite after baking data and mesh, nothing happens. I just see the baked mesh in the viewport but upon playing the timeline, nothing animates, the mesh is just sitting there. May I kindly know what I'm doing wrong? As for what I've already done is as follows:

1. Created a domain
2. Created effectors
3. Set Surface thickness and Surface Effector values to more than 0.0
4. Created a cone mesh inside the domain as a Flow object with Inflow.
5. Baked data
6. Waited…
7. Baked mesh
8. Waited…

I am really sorry I haven't uploaded a screenshot. I actually do not have one since I deleted the file that was having the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow object might be too small for your given resolution. Try Increasing it or set your flow object to planner, apparently it should make it work with the lower resolutions.

I'm also trying to make a fountain and until there's a adaptive domain for liquids I'm not sure if it's quite possible.